# SQL Server comparing server performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

I have SQL Server 2016 Standard installed on two different physical servers. Can you suggest a way I can compare the overall performance of these two servers?

For example, is there a query I can run against system tables that could give me a rough estimate of how much faster one server is than the other?

Comment: its difficult to compare apples to apples. check out this article. https://www.sentryone.com/white-papers/performance-baselines-and-benchmarks-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: One of the easiest things to baseline is maintenance tasks. Run full backups, DBCC CHECKDB, etc. Here's a [whitepaper I wrote for Google](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/new-white-paper-sql-server-performance-tuning-google-compute-engine/) that has more details.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to compare raw hardware performance, for that you have tons of tools around. Just type "server hardware performance" on your preferred search engine and you will get lot of options.

Other case is to compare SQL Server performance. Then, for starters, you will need to be sure that both have same configuration parameters. You can use [FirstResponderKit](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/) for that task. It will give you a handful scripts to monitor and and do a first triage of your servers, so you can have data to compare.

You could run a series of test and measure different performance parameters with tools like Perf Monitor and alike. I like to use [SQL Stress](http://www.sqlstress.com) to run a group of queries in loops, at the end it will also give you some useful data.